# Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be positive real numbers. What is the smallest possible value of...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be positive real numbers. What is the smallest possible value of $(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}\right)$?

---

I don't know how to approach this problem, though I think it might use the AM-GM inequality. Can someone please help?

Comment: Hint: The inequality is homogeneous so we may assume $a+b+c=1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Do you know why $ ( a + b+ c) ( \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} ) \geq 9 $?

> Arithmetic Mean - Harmonic Mean.

Hence, conclude that $ 2 ( a + b + c) ( \frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{b+c} + \frac{1}{c+a} ) \geq 9 $

When does equality occur?

Comment: Where does the factor 2 comes from.

Comment: Because you require the same numbers as there are in the denominator, $(a+b)+(b+c)+(c+a)= 2(a+b+c)$.

Comment: Alternatively, let $ x = a+b, y = b+c, z = c+a$ to see the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

AM-GM inequality is a good idea: 
\begin{align}
& (a + b + c)\left(\frac{1}{a + b} + \frac{1}{a + c} + \frac{1}{b + c}\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{2}((a + b) + (a + c) + (b + c))\left(\frac{1}{a + b} + \frac{1}{a + c} + \frac{1}{b + c}\right) \\
\geq & \frac{1}{2} \times 3\sqrt[3]{(a + b)(a + c)(b + c)} \times 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{(a + b)(a + c)(b + c)}} \\
= & \frac{9}{2}
\end{align}

The equality holds when $a + b = a + c = b + c$.

Comment: You can simplify the criterion for equality: $a + b = a + c = b + c \iff a = b = c$.

Comment: Sure, I intended to leave as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$((a+b)+(a+c)+(b+c))\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}\right) \ge (1+1+1)^2=9$$
$$\iff (a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}\right) \ge \frac{9}{2} $$