# How can I prove this inequality using HM-GM-AM-QM inequalities?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-writing

Given $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$, prove that $$(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{b+c} + \frac{1}{a+c}\right) \geq \frac{9}{2}$$

I've been trying for a couple of hours in total, and I just can't seem to get it to work no matter what I do.

Edit: I also realize this is a general problem-solving issue I have, as it requires me to pick the right option out of thousands of possible paths I could take with the proof. Is there a generalized way to approach these kinds of questions?

Comment: Unfortunately, no general method exists; creative thinking and insight are still needed.  Much as I tell students, "Derivatives are a science; integrals are an art."

Comment: (This is a response to the edit). There is no "general way". These problems often take hours at a time because they require multiple clever insights. To get better at quickly finding these, there are many inequality books and handouts. One place where you can find some of these is here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6_inequalities

Comment: @RobertTheTutor To be fair, the Risch algorithm can be used to solve any integral with an elementary antiderivative, and there likely are extensions of the algorithm to solve integrals while also including special functions. That being said, it's true that general methods to solve things don't always exist. If that were the case, then all of mathematics's problems would be solved and mathematicians would be left without a job.

Comment: @Kyky It would _really_ surprise me if there were no such extension to Risch, even knowing nothing about how it works, as what we choose to call elementary functions is entirely arbitrary. So if there were an algorithm that happened to work for exactly that choice and nothing else, I would find it very strange. Like an algorithm for solving equations that only works in base ten.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3682987/42969

Comment: Thank you very much for you insights regarding general problem-solving. I definitely need to work on my creativity.

Comment: @Arthur I mean surely there exists some extension from the "basic" Risch algorithm but the definition of elementary function isn't as arbitrary as it may seem, at least they can be described nicely via the algebra of differential fields.

Comment: @MartinR I tried to find my particular problem before posting, but google had turned up nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AM-HM inequality states that for $x,y,z\in\Bbb{R}_{>0}$ $$\frac{x+y+z}{3}\geq\frac{3}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}}\\\iff(x+y+z)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)\geq9$$ Now take $x=(a+b),y=(b+c)$ and $z=(c+a)$

**One More Proof Using the Famous Nesbitt's Inequality:**

$$(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}\right)\\=\left(\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{a+b}\right)+\left(\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{b+c}\right)+\left(\frac{a}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+c}\right)+\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\\=3+\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\ge3+\frac{3}{2}=\frac{9}{2}$$

The last step follows from the very well-known **Nesbitt's inequality**

$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: Makes total sense. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Change variables $\alpha=a+b$, $\beta=b+c$ and $\gamma=c+a$ to transform the LHS to

$$
\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\Big(\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}+\frac{1}{\gamma}\Big)\ .
$$

Now, AM-GM gives

$$
\alpha+\beta+\gamma\geq3\sqrt[3]{\alpha\beta\gamma}
$$

and

$$
\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}+\frac{1}{\gamma}\geq3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{\alpha\beta\gamma}}\ .
$$

Now just multiply the inequalities together.

Comment: Got it. Thank you kindly